# MD5 hash comparison over SMB SLOW

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-v5.0, md5

I'm scripting a full backup solution in powershell on Windows server 2016 for Hyper-V VM's and have run into the issue that calculating the MD5 hash over the network on a mounted network drive across a WAN is about half the speed of just doing the file copy itself over the WAN link. I've tried `certutil.exe` from the OS referencing the file across the share and it is extremely slow. I have also tried `Get-FileHash` in powershell with similar results. I have hundreds of 250MB files and have not been able to find a more efficient way of doing this without invoking a remote shell to run the command. Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: You're scripting a full backup? It sounds like you're reinventing the wheel. Have yo considered using one of the countless backup products/solutions that are available?

Comment: It's at a customers request that everything would be within powershell and native OS utilities. It works, just REALLY slow comparing MD5 backups over a 20Mbps link with tons of large files. They do not want to be reliant on 3rd party vendors for anything.

Comment: The Windows Server Backup feature is completely free and supports Hyper-V. Is that what you're scripting in Powershell?

Comment: Most likely the hash calculation reads such small blocks from the file that the protocol overhead becomes quite big, which degrades performance. Also the reading pattern of reading a block, calculating hash, reading next block makes it slower due to latency. In Linux I would use `cat` to print the file to `md5sum`. This will separate the file reading from calculating the hash value.

Comment: Tero, This is on Windows not NIX or I would just use rsync which would do all the lifting and verifying.